# Using FORM.getPartsArray() in Lucee

Tags: coldfusion, railo, lucee

Currently I'm working on a project to convert source code from ColdFusion to Lucee. I found an error occurs in Lucee, when using `FORM.getPartArray()`. Does Lucee have a similar function that can replace `FORM.getPartArray()`?

Example code:

```
<cfset var fileExt = 'png'>
<cfset var tmpPartsArray = FORM.getPartsArray() />
<cfif IsDefined("tmpPartsArray")>
    <cfloop array="#tmpPartsArray#" index="local.tmpPart">
        <cfif local.tmpPart.isFile() AND local.tmpPart.getName() EQ arguments.formField>
            <cfset fileExt = ListLast(local.tmpPart.getFileName(), ".")>
        </cfif>
    </cfloop>
</cfif>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also try `FORM.getFileItems()`. That array seems to contain only file fields.

```
<cfset Local.filesArray = FORM.getFileItems() />
<cfloop array="#Local.filesArray#" index="local.currFile">
    <cfset fileExt = ListLast(local.currFile.getName(), ".")>
</cfloop>
```

What is the purpose of the original code? As the file was already uploaded to the server, you could also move it to a safe directory with `<cffile action="upload">` and check `cffile.serverFileExt` instead.

Comment: i'm trying to make sure if the file is really is a file and having and extension.. i will get it's extension to the next process.. i'm tried to use getRaw() function but it seems when i call local.tmpPart.isFile() it returns error... is there any function to check the file like function isFile() ?

Comment: I don't think that's necessary with getFileItems() because the array only contains files. Otherwise, it is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly.

`FORM.getPartsArray()` is proprietary to Adobe, in Lucee you can try `FORM.getRaw()` but you'll probably have to do some work.

`getName()` will match but I'm not sure about the other ones.

Comment: This old Google Group post might help as well https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/railo/Np3mT412EUc